# Very high position_tolerance with inverse kinematics

Tags: ros, moveit, kinematics, inverse-kinematics

I finally managed to make my manipulator work also with Pose Goal using KDL as Inverse Kinematics plugin.
The problem is that I cannot in any way go below a certain level of position tolerance (0.12) which is too high to be able to pick up the objects on the table, is there any workaround?

My eef is `gripper_grasp_link` and I'd like to get on `arm_grasp_pose`, tried some kinematically compatible poses (in Joint Space and FK I can easily plan to and reach them) but nothing worked, here is a screenshot of the situation

[image]